# Why does Judaism.StackExchange have nearly triple as many questions as Islam.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, stackexchange

StackExchange is a pretty popular site around the world. If you consider the entire StackExchange network, it is well within the world's [top 50 most visited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297549/what-rank-is-stack-exchange-among-the-internet) platforms.

However I found it very interesting that this page `judaism.stackexchange.com`, has so much content, especially when you compare to a much larger religious group's page, like `Islam.stackexchange.com`.

The current stats are

```
Islam                         Judaism

questions   12k               questions 34k        
answers     19k               answers   52k
answered    82%               answered  84%
users       27k               users 15k
```

The proportion of users between `islam` and `judaism` (27:15) roughly matches the proporiton of Muslims to Jews in North America (assuming nobody else in the world uses StackExchange)

What then explains the massive difference in the number of questions and answers?

Does it demonstrate that Judaism has more rules and therefore more confusion? Does it demonstrate that Judaism is more open to interpretation? Could it simply be that there's another far more popular forum about Islam but not something similar for Judaism?

I'm interested to hear theories

Comment: How old is each site?

Comment: @DoubleAA Mi Yodeya is one year older: https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest

Comment: One possible reason: Q&A about Islam could be more prevalent in Arabic than Q&A about Judaism in Hebrew. Stack Exchange is English only.

Comment: There are also presumably many more Muslims than programmers, yet Stack Overflow has something like 2,000 times as many questions as Islam Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Alex but StackOverflow is four years older

Comment: @robev 1.5x as old hardly accounts for the additional 20 million questions.

Comment: @Alex Religions don't have new version updates every day. Also StackOverflow includes ALL programming languages

Comment: @CodyBugstein So perhaps Judaism has more version updates than Islam?

Comment: @Alex Depends on who you ask. Most Christians will say it's had at least one major revision since release, and most Muslims will say at least two.

Comment: 1. Can you link to an SEDE query? 2. How do these stats compare with others like https://christianity.stackexchange.com, https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/, and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a moderator on Islam.SE, I suspect the reason for that is highly cultural. A lot of Muslims who are actively *studying* the religion — those people who really tend to propel questions on a Stack Exchange site — are strongly disinclined to self-study, or studying outside of strictly regulated channels: You can't learn your religion from just *anyone*, it's important to learn it from people who are both knowledgeable and firm in belief until you have the skills and experience to differentiate good answers from bad yourself.

We do have a good core of knowledgeable people on Islam.SE, but they're far more likely to *answer* questions than to *ask* any.

As a result, Islam.SE still tends to get a lot of basic beginner and peer-support questions, which are typically not interesting to experts and often end up closed and/or roomba'd due to low quality. The sort of expert-level questions that really tend to make a Stack Exchange site thrive have been slow in coming, even after eight years.

Comment: I would venture to say that the Jewish approach to learning isn't that different from this, though.